# Calculate mean for panda databframe based on date

Tags: dataframe

In my dataset as follows (two columns: DATE and RATE)

[image]

I want to get the mean for the RATE for each day (from the dataset, you can see that there are multiple rate values for the same day). I have about 1,000 rows, so that I  am trying to find an easier way to calculate the mean for each day, then save the results to a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You have to group by date then aggregate
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html

In your case

```
df.groupby('DATE').agg({'RATE': ['mean']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby the date and perform mean operation.

```
new_df = df.groupby('DATE').mean()
```